# How can I wait until user gives or denies the permission request in Activity?

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, request

I want my code to wait until the user clicks something on the permission request pop up window, and then continue.

I have this in my RequestActivity, but I need the request results before the app loads up.

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        Task startupWork = new Task(async () => { await GetPermissions(); });
        startupWork.Start();

        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }

    public static async Task GetPermissions()
    {
        var permissionsStartList = new List<Permission>()
        {
            Permission.Storage,
            Permission.Camera
        };

        var permissionsNeededList = new List<Permission>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsStartList)
            {
                var status = await Plugin.Permissions.CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionsNeededList.Add(permission);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }

        var results = await Plugin.Permissions.CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permissionsNeededList.ToArray());

        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsNeededList)
            {
                var status = PermissionStatus.Denied;
                //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                if (results.ContainsKey(permission))
                    status = results[permission];
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could request the permission in the method `OnCreate` of MainActivity .

Comment: And it is possible to wait until the permission request is done, and then load the app?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        if (await GetPermissions())
           StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
```

Just a suggestion, don't navigate from `OnResume()`. Try from another path, class constructor.

Import this

> using System.Threading.Tasks;

```
public bool GetPermissions()
   {
      bool result;
      // EVERYTHING SAME AS YOUR CODE
        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsNeededList)
            {
                var status = PermissionStatus.Denied;
                //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                if (results.ContainsKey(permission))
                    status = results[permission];

                //If all permissions are set
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            result = false;
        }
    return result;
    }
```

Just made it simple without the return of the task.

Let me know if that's what you actually want or there's something else.

Comment: For the return task.Task part I get "the return expression must be of type of 'bool' rather than 'Task<bool>'" Should I just return true?

Comment: I didn't get such an error for my project, I use the same pattern for various things & it works perfectly for me. Try the updated code, maybe it will work, just added `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` & setresult to false in catch

Comment: If I return task.Task.Result I don't get an error, but the MainActivity starts immediately, it doesn't wait for user's respond.

Comment: just asking, why are you adding intent at onResume?

Comment: Should I just ask for the permissions in the MainActivity onCreate function?

Comment: i got a better & simple thing rather than making it complex & confusing for you

Comment: My cameraView gets called if the app loads up, and thats why I need the camera permission request in my Activity.
Now the app needs to be restarted if it is opened for the first time, because I get the permission after the camera gets called..

And that is what I want, I want my app to load up if the permission request is done.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

OnCreate function:

```
List<string> permissionNeededList = new List<string>();

if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != (int)Permission.Granted)
{
   permissionNeededList.Add(Manifest.Permission.Camera);
}
if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
{
   permissionNeededList.Add(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
}

if (permissionNeededList.Count == 0)
{
   LoadApplication(new App());
}
else
{
   ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, permissionNeededList.ToArray(), 1);
}
```

OnRequestPermissionsResult function:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
   LoadApplication(new App());
}
```